# Is it possible for Vue Router to display different layouts based on the parameter passed?

Tags: regex, vue.js, vue-router

I was wondering if it was possible for Vue Router to display different layouts based on the parameter passed in a URL?

Consider the following URL's:

- /admin/forms/pending
- /admin/forms/approved
- /admin/forms/declined
- /admin/forms/categories

The first 3 links relate to the status of some form objects, and will use the pending/approved/declined status to pass the parameter as a status filter to the forms API.  However, for the categories, I want this to display a view that lists all the categories instead.

I know that this is possible by having two different route objects - one that matches `/admin/forms/categories` and one that matches `/admin/form/:status`, but I was wondering if it was possible to combine the two, or have a way of creating the two routes so that it doesn't matter what order I define them (if I put my category route below the status route, then the category view won't show, for example).  For this, I thought something like (`/admin/forms/(:status(?!categories))` would work, but I am getting a "Nothing to repeat" error from Vue Router.

Is this something that is possible to do in Vue Router?  I'm more then happy to carry on defining the two different routes, just wondered if there was a more efficient way of doing this?

Thanks!

=====

UPDATE:  Don't ask me why but I was referencing Vuex here when it should have been Vue Router, d'oh

Comment: For me it is a bit difficult to understand wht you want. It will be more clear if you give some examples of URLs which match what you want, and some which do not match. Additionally, I wonder where did the colon `:` appear from.

Comment: Hi @virolino, thanks for the reply

Basically, I have a scenario where there are 2 matching URL patterns, but I want them to relate to 2 different views - if someone goes to `/admin/forms/pending` for example, it needs to show forms that have a status of pending, however if they go to `/admin/forms/categories` it needs to list form categories which are a seperate entity from forms.  I was just seeing if there was a way of doing this within one rule rather then having 2.  I hope that helps clear things up?

Answer (score 0):

By passing parameters to the page /admin/form/, you could have two components, one for the first three with one type layout; one for categories with a different layout. 
Using v-if ... v-else to switch between them.

Comment: Hi @Phoenix.

That's a good shout - I can check on the :status parameter to determine what route the user is intending to use, however I would ideally prefer to keep a separation of views, mainly because I'm annoyingly picky about stuff like that!!  That's a great idea though